# How to assign a pointer to a variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variables, pointers

I have a method which uses a mutable dictionary for some calculations (usersDictionary), when the UITableView is in search mode there is another mutable dictionary to use for calculation (searchDictionary). That's a long method and I don't want to check `if (tableView == self.tableView)` on every step to see if I have to use usersDictionary or searchDictionary.
I want to do something like this in the beginning of the method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *inUseDictionary;
if (tableView == self.tableView)
    inUseDictionary = _contactsDictionary;
else
    inUseDictionary = _searchResult;
```

Then I use `inUseDictionary` whether the tableView is in searchMode or not, and the changes has been made to `inUseDictionary` during calculations will affect the corresponding dictionary (`usersDictionary` or `searchDictionary`), and at the end of the method, release the `inUseDictionary`.

is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried? This should work.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch i showed an example of this code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, as you described:

```
    NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"one", @"two", nil];
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"one", @"two", nil];

    NSMutableArray *inUseArray;

    if (true)
        inUseArray = array1;
    else
        inUseArray = array2;

    [inUseArray removeLastObject];
    [inUseArray addObject:@"three"];

    inUseArray = nil;

    NSLog(@"array1: %@", array1);
    NSLog(@"array2: %@", array2);
    NSLog(@"inUseArray: %@", inUseArray);
```

Result:

```
2014-03-08 13:48:53.193 test[74296:70b] array1: (
    test,
    one,
    three
)
2014-03-08 13:48:53.196 test[74296:70b] array2: (
    test,
    one,
    two
)
2014-03-08 13:48:53.196 test[74296:70b] inUseArray: (null)
```

Comment: I don't know why this should work! If those 3 variables are pointed to same address in memory, when you change array1 why array2 is still unchanged?

Comment: array1 and array2 are completely separate. They are allocated in the first two lines separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try code like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSDictionary *inUseDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bSearchType; //If you need a judgement for current dictionary type

if(/*change to searchMode*/){
    self.inUseDictionary = _searchResult;
    self.bSearchType = YES;
}
else{
    self.inUseDictionary = _contactsDictionary;
    self.bSearchType = NO;
}
```

in tableDataSource, delegate or any where else, just to use self.inUseDictionary, it will affect the corresponding dictionary. Using self.bSearchType if you want to know which dictionary you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ** and dereference as needed.

```
NSMutableDictionary **inUseDictionary;
if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    inUseDictionary = &_contactsDictionary;
} else {
    inUseDictionary = &_searchResult;
}
```

Comment: Cool!! didn't know it! Does it point inUseDictionary to memory address of each dictionaries?